# Mounting micro-SD in ubuntu 18.04 throws "already mounted or mount point busy"

Tags: 18.04, partitioning, mount, sd-card

I'm trying to get a micro-SD to work on my machine since I'm running out of space.

```
fdisk -l


Disk /dev/mmcblk2: 14.9 GiB, 15931539456 bytes, 31116288 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000
```

Now when trying to mount it to a folder I created it responds with:

```
mount -t vfat /dev/mmcblk2 /mnt/SD
mount: /mnt/SD: /dev/mmcblk2 already mounted or mount point busy.
```

EDIT:
After, as suggested, using `lsblk` instead, it listed the following:

```
NAME         MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0          7:0    0 215.5M  1 loop
mmcblk3      179:0    0   3.6G  0 disk
|-mmcblk3p1  179:1    0   8.5K  0 part
|-mmcblk3p2  179:2    0   8.5K  0 part
|-mmcblk3p3  179:3    0   128M  0 part
|-mmcblk3p4  179:4    0     1K  0 part
|-mmcblk3p5  179:5    0 953.7M  0 part /mnt/ro
`-mmcblk3p6  179:6    0   2.5G  0 part /mnt/rw
mmcblk3boot0 179:8    0     2M  1 disk
mmcblk3boot1 179:16   0     2M  1 disk
mmcblk3rpmb  179:24   0   512K  0 disk
```

So it appears that the SD-card hasn't been mounted automatically.

Comment: SD-cards usually get mounted automatically. You can check that with `lsblk`. `fdisk -l` does not show whether the disk is mounted or not

Comment: @EmreTalha Thanks for the suggestion, I have edited my question. Unforrtunalty it seems as if the SD-Card hasn't been mounted automatically.

Comment: Please show the *whole output* of `lsblk`, do not remove any lines. And if you add some options, there will be even more information, that helps us understand what you have and what you can do to make things work as you wish: `lsblk -o name,size,fstype,label,mountpoint,model`

Comment: Use the loop option for mount if you really want a partitionless sd card.  Better to add a partition table, then a partition, then a filesystem, and it then gets treated as a normal device for mounting.

Comment: If what you show now is the whole output of the lsblk command line, you have a very special set of drives and partitions. What operative system is it (for example Ubuntu Desktop or Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS), and what kind of computer (brand name and model number)? If you are still not showing any output of the other drives, please show the whole output from the lsblk command line that I suggested in a previous comment.  Anyway, we need more information to be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
mount -t vfat /dev/mmcblk2 /mnt/SD
```

Even if your system were recognizing mmcblk2 as a block storage device, this wouldn't work--you mount storage partitions with readable filesystems to filepaths, not entire storage devices.

So *if* your system recognized mmcblk2 as a storage device, you would mount mmcblk2p1 or mmcblk2p2 to /mnt/SD, not mmcblk2. Doing so would look more like this:

```
mount -t vfat /dev/mmcblk2p1 /mnt/SD
```

However, unless you aren't including the entire output of *lsblk*, then your SD card isn't being recognized by your computer as a block storage device.

You need to:

1.) Restart/reboot your computer.

2.) **Insert your SD card.**

3.) Check for *mmcblk2* in the output of *lsblk*.

- If *mmcblk2* isn't listed in the output of *lsblk* after rebooting it, check for *mmcblk2* in the output of *fdisk -l* again.
- If *mmcblk2* **is not** in the output of *lsblk*, but **is** in the output of *fdisk -l*, then perhaps there is an issue with the device's partition(s) and/or formatting that prevents it from being recognized as a valid block storage device by your system. In which case, you will need to format it using the *fdisk* utility.

4.) If *mmcblk2* needs to be reformatted, you can do so using the following commands:

```
sudo fdisk /dev/mmcblk2
```

- Inside the interactive fdisk console:

*fdisk console:*

```
g           # Create new GPT table.
n           # Create new partition.    
1           # Create partition 1.    
[ENTER]     # Default start sector.    
[ENTER]     # Default end sector.    
w           # Write changes to disk and exit.
```

- Back on the command line, create the filesystem for the partition:

*bash command line:*

```
sudo mkfs.vfat /dev/mmcblk2p1
```

- Create the filepath and mount the storage device:

*bash command line:*

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/SD
sudo mount -t vfat /dev/mmcblk2p1 /mnt/SD
```